# How to show the support status of packages in freya?

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, software-installation, package-management, software-sources

I've recently read this article (http://www.heise.de/open/meldung/Ubuntu-LTS-Lauter-Sicherheitsluecken-trotz-Langzeitpflege-3181830.html - sorry, it's in German) about Canonical's LTS policies and how there are lots of packages that have a considerably shorter support cycle than the main distribution.

That made me curious about the support status of the packages in my system (freya 0.3.2).

So I ran

> ubuntu-support-status

but all the output I got was:

> *****@*****-Inspiron-5559:~$ ubuntu-support-status Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 133,
>   in 
>       pkg.name, support_tag)   File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 49, in get_maintenance_status
>       raise Exception("No date tag found") Exception: No date tag found
>   *****@*****-Inspiron-5559:~$

Shortly afterwards I got a crash report prompt.

I just assumed that the command would work in freya because freya is based on Ubuntu. But apparently it doesn't, so my questions are:

1. Is the command generally supposed to work in freya?
2. If yes, what could be the problem? / If not, how do I figure out the support status of the packages installed in my system?

**EDIT Oct 3 2016: output in Loki**
In the meantime I've switched to Loki. The output upon running ubuntu-support-status now is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 135, in 
>       pkg.name, support_tag)
>     File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 45, in get_maintenance_status
>       raise Exception("No Release file found for %s" % pkgname)
>   Exception: No Release file found for accountsservice

Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

While what you saw was [likely a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/211848/49899) and I'm on Loki (the next release) and unable to check this in Freya, I think there are a few things worth clarifying. While elementary OS is based on Ubuntu Long Term Support editions, "support" has a really specific scope. Major Ubuntu releases are "supported" with fixes and upgrades [for nine months](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) and the five-year "long term support" is reserved to critical/security patches. The elementary OS is based atop Ubuntu but holds its own release schedule and [rarely has time to support prior releases](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8266/5565) following the next's release, save for major issues. (And there are surely plenty of bugs to squash in Loki...) This is all to say that elementary OS "support" is closer to nine months/one year: the latest release. While you can remain on Freya and hopefully receive Ubuntu's upstream base security updates, the rest of the elementary stuff atop Ubuntu will be left behind early into that five-year support period. But there likely isn't enough planning within the project to give an official list of *supported* software when it changes so often.

For `ubuntu-support-status`, which is a part of [`ubuntu-update-core`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager), as far as I can tell, this is not intended to work with elementary OS, isn't included in the default repos, and hasn't been discussed in the bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks wolf - I've tried the same in Loki now, see the output above

Comment: @deesnook: I would ask the second part as a separate question (since this one already has a lot) but ultimately would try [upgrading `python3-apt`](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com&q=subject:%22%5C%5BBug+1503979%5C%5D+Re%5C%3A+ubuntu%5C-support%5C-status+throws+exeption+No+date+tag+found+%5C(regression%5C)%22&o=newest&f=1)