# How do the system requirements compare between elementary OS releases?

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, system-installation, hardware, luna

I don't see a record on the website of the differences in minimum/recommended system requirements between elementary OS releases (Luna 0.2, Freya 0.3, and Loki 0.4). Are they the same between releases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for the previous elementary OS release [quickly wanes after the next's release](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/22rhi3/how_long_is_luna_supported_for/), though the release's base Ubuntu is supported five years from its release (see [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions)).

## [Loki (0.4)](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation)

<sup>Based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus</sup>

- **Same as Freya**, but no longer supports 32-bit processors (only 64-bit)

## [Freya (0.3)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416153313/http://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#installation)

<sup>Based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr</sup>

> **Recommended System Specifications** [*Note: Still supports 32-bit processors*]
>
> - Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
> - 1 GB of system memory (RAM)
> - 15 GB of disk space
> - Internet access

## [Luna (0.2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150217150054/http://elementary.io/docs/user-guide/technical-specifications)

<sup>Based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin</sup>

> **Minimum System Requirements**
>
> - 1 GHz x86 processor
> - 512MB of system memory (RAM)
> - 5GB of disk space
> - Graphics card and display capable of at least 1024x768
> - CD/DVD drive or ability to boot to a USB drive
>
> Users may be able to install Luna on devices that do not meet these requirements, but the experience is likely to suffer.
>
> **System Recommendations**
>
> - 1 GHz x86 processor
> - 1GB of system memory (RAM)
> - 15 GB of disk space
> - Graphics card and display capable of at least 1024x768
> - 3D compositing
> - CD/DVD Drive or ability to boot to a USB drive
> - Internet access

## Jupiter (0.1)

- **[Unlisted](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1719268)**